# Twig use one value in different for loop

Tags: symfony, twig

Since I'm using a SaaS platform I don't have much space to do things differently.

I have two for loops in Twig:

```
 {% for option in product.options %}
  {{ option.title }}
   {% if option.values %}
    {% for value in option.values %}     
     {{ value.title }}
    {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}  
  {% endfor %} 

{% for variant in product.variants %}
 {{ variant.stock.level }}
{% endfor %}
```

What I try to do is to use `variant.stock.level` value inside the `product.options` for loop to show some HTML. This value always match the corresponding index value of the other for loop. I also think that's the only way to do this.

So what I mean is.....Let's say both for loops contain 3 elements.

Option1
Option2
Option3

Variant1
Variant2
Variant3

So option1 needs to have the value from variant1.

For the end result I need to know what the value of eg Variant1 is to show some HTML like so:

```
{% for value in option.values %}   

 {% check if value from corresponding variant is greater then 0 %}
   <li class="on-stock">{{ value.title }}</li>  
 {% else %} 
   <li class="out-of-stock">{{ value.title }}</li>
 {% endif %}


{% endfor %}
```

I don't know no other way to explain this :) Any help appreciated....

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [attribute](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html).

> The attribute function can be used to access a "dynamic" attribute of a variable

Since the indexes are the same, you can use `loop.index0`

Example for your case

```
{% if attribute(option.variants, loop.index0) > 0 %}
    // some stuff
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thx but I don't fully understand how this might work in my case. With `option.variants` you mean `option.values`? Can you perhaps add an example?

Comment: Could you provide input and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly but you may use key from first loop to access product.variants with the same index.

```
{% for key, option in product.options %}
  {{ option.title }}
  {% if option.values %}
    {% for value in option.values %}     
      {{ value.title }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}  
  {{ product.variants[key].stock.level }}
{% endfor %}
```